# Android create multiple file inside a folder in internal storage

Tags: android

I am able to create a folder with following code but not able to add a multiple files inside a folder.

```
                             public void onClick(View v) {
                    // storage.createDirectory("MyDirName/MySubDirectory");

                 File myFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "/Images/abc/");
                 myFile.mkdirs();
                 try {
                   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                      String ab = i + ".png";
                     File file = new File(getFilesDir()
                             +File.separator
                             +"myDirectory" //folder name
                             +File.separator
                             +ab); //file name
                         file.createNewFile();
               }
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

         }
     }
```

please suggest me where i am doing wrong or how to add multiple files inside a folder?

Comment: You have to create the folder first. And then, the files inside it.

Comment: @Der Golem Yes, it does. But he's not trying to put the files inside that folder. He's trying to put them inside "myDirectory".

Comment: @joao2fast4u: Right. I overlooked that he was using a different directory.

Comment: thanks for the help i found the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, supposing you want to put your multiple files inside /Images/abc/ folder. You should use your folder path when creating you files. Like this:

```
         File myFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "/Images/abc/");
             myFile.mkdirs();
             try {
               for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                  String ab = i + ".png";
                 File file = new File(myFile.getAbsolutePath()//folder path
                         +File.separator
                         +ab); //file name
                     file.createNewFile();
           }
              } catch (IOException e) {

             e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

That will do the job :D